# what is the probability of landing 10 heads in a row given a certain amount of time.

Tags: probability

the guys at mythbusters managed to do it after 10 hours of a single person doing the tossing. my question is, what is the probability of an event such as this one happening as a function of time passing?. it would have obviously taken a shorter time if just had to land 5 instead of 10. but what if you had 10 minutes instead of 10 hours? how do you prove that it will be more likely to get 10 heads if you try for 10 hours?

Comment: it depends how many throws you did in the time.

Answer (score 0):

Let's call "Trying for 10 minutes" a "large attempt". A large attempt has some probability of succeeding (exactly what that probability is depends on how fast you're throwing). I would think it rather obvious that if you do 60 large attempts (i.e. keep going for 10 hours), then you have an increased probability of experiencing a success than if you do only one.